# PCA analysis on two datasets

Tags: r, data-visualization, pca

I am new in statistics and would like to test correlations between two datasets I have:

1. Biomarkers (6) activity on 14 populations. (columns:site, cat, gr, gst...)
2. Metals (24) in tissue for the same 14 populations. (columns: site, Fe, Ni, Co,.)

My question: How is the biomarkers activity correlated with concentration of metals in animal tissue?

I'm using R, and would be great if anyone knows how to visualize this question, maybe by using PCA?

Comment: You need a CCA (Canonical Correlation Analysis).

Comment: Or some sort of regression analysis (perhaps reduced-rank regression) if you want to predict one set of variables from another set of variables.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like canonical correlation analysis (CCA) to me.

R has canonical correlation (`cancor`).

Depending on the dimensions of your dataset it might not be possible: if your datamatrices are singular then standard CCA will not work. As far as I can see one of your datamatrices is singular with the size 14-by-24. I have worked a bit on singular CCA and I tried two ways: Canonical ridge (regularized CCA) and PCA projection followed by CCA in the reduced space. There seems to be an R package called `CCA` with canonical ridge [1]. I haven't tried that one. I worked in Matlab.

[1] https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v023i12/v23i12.pdf